# Editing a nested list in R

Tags: r, list

I have a nested list named `places` in R which has 42 lists of list length 17. My goal is to remove the last 2 elements of my list in each of the 42 lists so that I end up with 42 lists of list length 15.

I can return one of the unwanted nested lists thus:

```
placeholder <- lapply(1:length(places), function(x) places[[x]][[16]])
```

However, I am struggling with the syntax that would set the 16th and 17th nested lists to NULL. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `lapply(places, function(x) x[1:15])`

Comment: @AllanCameron
Out of curiosity, if I wanted to set the last 2 elements of each of the said 42 lists in `places` to, say, `999` then how could I do that? Thank you

Comment: `lapply(places, function(x) {x[[16]] <- 999; x[[17]] <- 999; x})`

Comment: `... x[16:17] <- 999 ...`

Comment: @AllanCameron
@r2evans
Thank you both. I had worked out the below, which obviously less elegant:
`lapply(seq_along(places), \(x) {places[[x]][16:17] <- 999; places[[x]]})`